# Eclipse plugin CMSIS Packs manager is stuck on downloading CMSIS Packs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I'm following instructions on this page :
https://eclipse-embed-cdt.github.io/plugins/packs-manager/

Plugin should refresh/initialilly download various CMSIS Packs for various boards/MCUs from various vendors...
However, it freezes always on the same pack name - AnalogDevices.ADuCM320_DFP.pdsc
It gives no error just hangs in there forever...

Any hint, advice how to avoid this weird situation (I only need packs for boards/MCUs from ST).

Thanks in advance,
regards.

Comment: Since the packs' index is downloaded from Keil, you might like to check if it is accessible from there. As the linked page says, the index if commonly out of sync. Most probably this is a Keil issue, not one of the plugin.

Comment: What I think is that plugin should give some kind of feedback. This particular device is not the first one checked... Is there any way to do this procedure manually ?

Comment: AFAIK many plugins and the IDE animate a progress bar on the right side of the bottom status bar, and in the progress view.

Comment: Same problem for me. Looked up this device on https://www.keil.com/pack/index.pidx and found out, that the link resolves to a page not found website.

Answer (score 0):

have found the same problem already discussed.
https://github.com/eclipse-embed-cdt/eclipse-plugins/discussions